# 2.4GHZ US Wireless Device in EU

Tags: wireless

I want to buy the Fishman Triple Play (a 2.4Ghz wireless guitar hex to MIDI pickup) and there are two versions, the US one and the EU/UK one. The US one is loads cheaper and I live in Malta (Europe) will I have problems with it? What are the repurcussion of using a 2.4Ghz devise designed for the US in the EU? are there technical problems or just legal issues?

Some people and also Fishman (manufacturer) states that the devices might work but there could be some problems. Can someone please shed some light?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manufacturer specifically says that different bands are used in Europe compared to the US.

[image]

If the band is occupied, now or in the future, you could interfere with someone else's signal or your signal could be interfered with. In many places it can be illegal to use non-approved devices, which in practice means that it could be confiscated at customs or if you interfere with someone else, it could cause issues.

Can you get away with it? It's hard to verify their story or whether it's likely to result in interference (worst-case they're lying to prevent the type of arbitrage you want to do).

The US bands used are 2404.0 MHz to 2480.0 MHz, according to their [FCC](https://www.fcc.gov/) submission.

[image]

Here's the [European spectrum allocation](http://www.onlineconversion.com/downloads/european_frequency_allocations.pdf) in that range:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This was extremely helpful! Thanks a lot! I guess I'll better save up for the EU and be safe then :)

Thanks as lot!!!

Comment: I know this is closed, but I think that you can safely use the US version. The only problem is that the 2.4GHz in Europe is full of crap, so you might get interference, but it actually depends on the modulation used. You won't encounter legal issues for sure, the 2.4G is used for wifi and radio controlled models... Basically anyone with ten fingers can transmit and receive on that band.

Comment: Vladimir... Thanks a lot for your comment, greatly appreciated!!! Sorry for my ignorance but a nearby WIFI might interfere (in the same room)?